# CAST() function MYSQL doesn't seem to work for me? need help please

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hi everyone so the issue I am having is that I am trying to use the CAST() function to change a column where the values are stored as varchars into signed(64 bit integers) so that I can sort the table by the value of the integers in that column. Below I am sharing the code I am using in  MYSQL and an image of the table so you can see what it is I am working with. The problem is when I try to sort by emp_id after running the code it still won't sort properly based on the integer value and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SHOW databases;
USE ex;
SHOW tables;
SELECT * 
FROM string_sample;
SELECT CAST(emp_id AS SIGNED), emp_name,
FROM string_sample;
```

[image: MYSQL Table]

Comment: Haven't you forgotten about the 'order by' clause?

Comment: even with the ````ORDER BY```` it still is not ordering them correctly because the emp_id column is stored as varchar, not an integer so it still orders them incorrectly. I know it's something to do with the way I'm using the ````CAST()```` function that is causing the problem I'm just not sure what I am doing wrong with it or what I'm missing. It just is not converting the emp_id to an integer for some reason.

Comment: You could also write: SELECT CAST(emp_id AS SIGNED), emp_name,
FROM string_sample order by CAST(emp_id AS SIGNED) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved seems to be what was causing the issue was that after my use of `CAST(emp_id AS SIGNED)` I didn't give it an alias when I changed the line to `CAST(emp_id AS SIGNED) AS emp_id` the table behaved correctly and converted emp_id to an int which allowed me to sort it by the emp_id values correctly.